# Centos 7 sendmail sending emails to incorrect ip address

Tags: centos7, sendmail

Sorry, I am new to Centos 7 and sendmail.

My email server was working but I had to restart the server. After restarting the email server suddenly fail to send emails to specific domain under my control.

I checked the /var/log/maillog

Oct 26 17:02:03 a_domain sendmail[xxxx]: xxxxx: to=<b@b_domain.com>, delay=00:02:00, xdelay=00:02:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=121209, relay=b_domain.com. [b_domain_ip_address], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with b_domain.com.

b_domain_ip_address is ip of shopify hosting provider and not the mx record ip address I am expecting. From previous maillog, before restarting the b_domain_ip_address was correctly resolving to our email provider.

Comment: Make sure the DNS on the machine resolves correctly, If no Mx exists it will try to use a record instead, so maybe there was a temporary failure when Mx was attempted.

Comment: I did a nslookup -q=MX b_domain.com to check the mx record from server and it is resolving the to the exchange server of our email provider.